# TCP client failed to send string to server

Tags: c, linux, tcp, send

I am programming  TCP server client. I sending the three string seperately using seperate `send` system call.
But receiving end i getting only single string that is first string which i send. remaining two string missed.

Below i given the part of my server client program.

client.c

```
char *info = "infolog";
char *size = "filesize";
char *end = "fileend";
send(client, info, strlen(info)+1, 0);
send(client, size, strlen(size)+1, 0);
send(client, end, strlen(end)+1, 0);
```

server.c

```
while ((read_size = recv(client, msg, sizeof(msg), 0))) {
    printf("Data: %s\n", msg);
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
}
```

Actual output:

```
Data: infolog
```

Expected output

```
Data: infolog
Data: filesize
Data: fileend
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try printing out `read_size`. It's likely that you received all three messages at the same time.

Comment: @Mike you are right. i receiving strlen of all there string. Why server not receiving it separately?

Comment: see Basile's answer below. TCP is stream-based, so you may receive more output than has been sent already, or less, depending on network conditions, buffering, etc.

Comment: "more output than has been sent already" - lol. What I meant to say was more output than you would expect after sending a single small `send()` (especially when you know they are immediately followed by other `send()` calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out `read_size`. You probably have received all the messages already.

Due to [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), the sender probably batched up your three `send()` calls and sent a single packet to the server. While you can disable Nagle's algorithm, I don't think it's a good idea in this case. Your server needs to be able to handle receiving of partial data, and handle receiving more data than it expects.

You might want to look into using an upper-layer protocol for your messages, such as [Google Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/). Take a look at the [techniques](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques) page, where they describe how they might do it: build up a protocol buffer, and write its length to the stream before writing the buffer itself. That way the receive side can read the length and then determine how many bytes it needs to read before it has a complete message.

Comment: Is it has any possible method to achieve my need? I already implemented most of the code in TCP. So changing protocol not possible.

Comment: @sujin: No, not really. You have to design your protocol and your applications to manage byte streams, there is no notion of "application message" in TCP. Your code should bear with that.

Comment: And actually, if you don't deal with that, you have not correctly implemented your code: you made a huge design mistake.

Comment: @sujin not necessarily. If you implement a UDP-based protocol, you must implement the reliability yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is not a message protocol but a byte stream protocol.

The three `send`-s  could be `recv`-ed as a single input (or something else, e.g. in two or five `recv` etc....)

The application should analyze the input and buffer it to be able to splice it in meaningful messages.

<sup>the transmission may split or merge the messages, e.g. intermediate routers can and will split or merge the "packets".</sup>

In practice you'll better have some good conventions about your messages. Either decide that each message is e.g. newline terminated, or decide that it starts with some header giving its size.

Look at [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP), [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP), [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP), [SCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCGI) or [ONC/XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) (documented in [RFC5531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5531)) as concrete examples. And document quite well your protocol (a minima, in long descriptive comments for some homework toy project, and more seriously, in a separate public document).